# Magento Product Addtocart go to Checkout Page by skipping Cart Page gives suggested Tutorial or any information

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, checkout

Please Suggest Tutorial or any example How to change exciting controller using local folder and local code. I want change in cart controller. I do when click on Add To Cart then it redirects to checkout page. Please Tell What I change and How to change. I am making cart controller override. It's working, but what can change in this controller to direct redirect to check out page.

Comment: I got answers here Please Check It on [link for this Question answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/magento-product-addtocart-go-to-checkout-page-by-skipping-cart-page-gives-sugges?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: `require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class My_Module_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
        $this->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $returnUrl);
        parent::addAction();
    }
} `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class My_Module_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
        $this->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $returnUrl);
        parent::addAction();
    }
}
```